# Quartz : There is no DataSource named 'myDS'

Tags: quartz-scheduler

When i use datasource name as "quartzDS" everything is working fine, but when i change datasource name to any other name any other like "myDS". i get error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'myDS'
```

My quartz.properties file.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = QuartzClusterScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 100
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 8
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 5000
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL = java:jboss/myDS
```

Comment: Did you do a workspace text search for `quartzDS` to see if it's defined elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Resolved, Changed from

```
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDS.jndiURL = java:jboss/myDS
```

to

```
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.jndiURL = java:jboss/myDS
```

Comment: Do you know, how must be named quartz table where it write info when trigger ocoured?