# Quartz Spring Boot There is no DataSource named 'dataSource'

Tags: java, spring-boot, datasource, quartz

I have the following `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=dataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=qrtz_

org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=1
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
org.quartz.plugin.triggerHistory.class=org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
```

Also, I added `QuartzConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class QuartzConfiguration {

    public static final String CONTEXT_KEY = "applicationContext";

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setApplicationContextSchedulerContextKey("applicationContext");
        scheduler.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("quartz.properties"));
        scheduler.setDataSource(dataSource);
        scheduler.setWaitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
        return scheduler;
    }

}
```

In the `application.properties` I have defined:

```
#PostgreSQL
spring.datasource.url=${postgresql.datasource.url}
spring.datasource.username=${postgresql.datasource.username}
spring.datasource.password=${postgresql.datasource.password}
```

Right now, during start up the application fails with the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Failed to obtain DB connection from data source 'dataSource': java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'dataSource' [See nested exception: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'dataSource']
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:783)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX.getNonManagedTXConnection(JobStoreTX.java:71)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.executeInNonManagedTXLock(JobStoreSupport.java:3861)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:839)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.schedulerStarted(JobStoreSupport.java:695)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: There is no DataSource named 'dataSource'
    at org.quartz.utils.DBConnectionManager.getConnection(DBConnectionManager.java:104)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.getConnection(JobStoreSupport.java:780)
    ... 49 more
```

What am I doing wrong and how to provide a correct DataSource to the `org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource` ?

Comment: Does reading through https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/27709 help?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! I removed `org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX` and now it starting fine!

Comment: This config works with older version of spring boot (2.5.0), later versions won't work.
I was using spring boot 2.6.7 and I struggled for couple of hours to figure this out, later with the above github link I got the resolution. Below is the property needed to be changed - 
form this - org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
to this - 
org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStor

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. create a configuration bean that specifically creates you DataSource.

   ```
        @Bean
        public DataSource getDataSource()
        {
            DataSourceBuilder dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
            dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
            dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:file:C:/temp/test");
            dataSourceBuilder.username("sa");
            dataSourceBuilder.password("");
            return dataSourceBuilder.build();
        }
   ```
2. You can alternatively use JNDI, use the spring.datasource.jndi-name

[see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327762/quartz-there-is-no-datasource-named-myds)

Comment: Thanks, but datasource is already created and accesible by `@Autowired private DataSource dataSource;`